# what is the mean chan word in struct definition in golang

Tags: go

I'm reading Ethereum code,
what is the mean following

`<-chan struct{}`
and
`chan<- error`?

```
type protoRW struct {
   Protocol
   in     chan Msg        // receives read messages
   closed <-chan struct{} // receives when peer is shutting down
   wstart <-chan struct{} // receives when write may start
   werr   chan<- error    // for write results
   offset uint64
   w      MsgWriter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list inside the `struct { ... }` is the list of [field declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#FieldDecl). The `Protocol` field at the top is an [embedded field declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#EmbeddedField). The rest is declared using the `<FieldName> <FieldType>` format. For example `closed <-chan struct{}` is a field named `closed` whose type is `<-chan struct{}` (a *receive-only* [channel](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) whose element type is the empty-struct). And `werr chan<- error` is a field named `werr` of type `chan<- error` (a *send-only* channel whose element type is `error`).